# How to add log message before camel-ftp starts?

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

How to add log message before ftp starts ?
to following route:

```
from("ftp://...idempotentKey=..&idempotentRepository=#MyRepo&delay=..")
    .to("file://folder/output");
```

1. Log message should contain that ftp started.
2. Log message should contain filter result whether file processed before or not.
3. This messages have logLevel=INFO

pollEnrich is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it, your route is starting as soon execution is hitting your "from" instruction, then you can log the beginning with a simple java log instruction just before.

Additionally, you can also delay, change startup order, or remove automatic start, [documented here](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html).

To your second question, about logging your ftp client activity, you can do it that way:

```
from("ftp://...idempotentKey=..&idempotentRepository=#MyRepo&delay=..")
.log("Processing ${file:name}")
.to("file://folder/output");
```

Comment: .log(...) is not printed because of route is not reached to this point. idempotent key will be duplicate second time. so this solution is not good.

Comment: Then you can log the beginning with a simple java log instruction just before.
as said...